# binding .a file with the .so shared library file in linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, libtool

I have one .a file ( ar command ) which I want to bind it with my .so file during GCC compilation.

How can I do this.

If I run this command :

```
gcc /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.a ../../ndagentlibc/obj/*.o tideways_xhprof.o tracing.o -shared -o libhello.so


nm libhello.so | grep apr_term

output:  U    apr_terminate
```

apr_terminate is not getting its defination

Comment: Ex: gcc ../libnd.a tideways_xhprof.o tracing.o -shared -o libhello.so .. is it good ?

Comment: nope, see my answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

If your `.so` file needs the `.a` file, link your `.so` with the `.a` file and all of the needed code from the `.a` archive will be available in the `.so` file.

Comment: please, look at the linker documentation... parameter order is essential for object modules in archive files to be selected.  they are only selected if some unsolved reference is already detected that can be solved including the module from the archive... else the module will not be included in the final executable.

Comment: @LuisColorado of course, i was under the impression your SO is the component that needs the A. If that is not the case, you can’t bundle it in the SO file, it’s not like a macOS framework that can embed any type of resource.

Comment: Nope, you are doing a mixed linking, with `.so` files to be dynamically loaded at runtime, and `.o` static objects, bound at linking time.  It is common to archive them in a `.a` archive, as the linker only uses the required ones.  But for a file to be selected you need to have triggered the unresolved before.  You can add the `.o` to the `.so` when linking the `.so` or later to the final executable, always, when linking the `.so`  both strategies are possible.

Comment: btw, the `.a` is not a resource... it's only an archive... It has nothing special but the linker goes into it, and gets from there only what is neccessary at that time.  It simplifies the linking of a library with numerous static objects only...

Comment: @LuisColorado I think we misunderstand each other

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your command and put the `.a` library at the end...

```
gcc ../../ndagentlibc/obj/*.o tideways_xhprof.o tracing.o -shared -o libhello.so /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.a
```

as the `ld(1)` linker only selects the object modules (`*.o`) included in a library archive that it knows have unsolved references for *at the moment of reading it* (as you put it first in your command line, no unsolved references appear by that time, so no library `.o` component is selected and included at the time of library processing)

In the case of an archive of object modules, the linker tries to do its best, selecting only the ones that appear to be necessary, and putting an archive at first makes the linker to select no files from it to be linked.

## note

BTW, the `-shared` option is used to create a shared object (a `.so` module) which probably is not what you want.  If you want to create a final executable program, don't use `-shared`.  I point at this, because the first time I had to fight with this, I assumed the kind of linking (shared or static) was specified with some option (common mistake, I think)  but the kind of linking is actually given, object by object, by the kind of file you feed to the linker, and not with a command line option.  Apart of other things, it makes the linker *not to comply when some references are missing in the program* (it assumes those will be resolved in a later linking)